# Two drop down dynamically populated from two mysql tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, jqwidget

I'm creating a form with jqwidgets. I successfully done the grid.
Now I need to add a form with more than two dropdowns.

One dropdown should load data from a table called `products` and other one should load from `suppliers`.

Tables:

```
-Categories
   ID, CategoryName
-products
  ProductID,  ProductName
-prices
  PriceId, productId, supplierid, date, price
-suppliers
supplierid, suppliername
```

Please help me create a form so I can update the price table. I need to dynamically populate the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can load with simple SQL query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
echo "<select>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<option>$row['ProductName']</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

P.S: Don't forget name for  & value for . You can do the same query for supplier as well.

Comment: How can I populate the second dropdown?

Comment: Change products to any other database table you want and change the values in while loop.

Comment: It woks with normal drop-down. Anyone can help me to load data from  database tables to diffrent jqwidget drop-down?

I mean a single form with two jqwidget drop-down. both should be populated from diffrent tables...

Comment: @RiyasRawther repeat the same process for both <select>, first query for 1st select and 2nd as well. What's the issue?